# Just installed Ubuntu on Windows, is there a way to boot into Ubuntu using Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu on Windows 10 now and wonder if it's possible to actually boot into Ubuntu through Windows 10. Anyone knows?

[image: Ubuntu On Windows Screenshot]

Comment: it's meant more for developers, ssh, git, ruby, ect. - command line stuff.

Comment: You can automatically start Ubuntu when Windows starts. You can also run Ubuntu GUI instead of just terminal if you want. However it is unclear what exactly you are asking to do when you say "boot".

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu on Windows is a product distributed by Microsoft for their Windows 10 operating system.

It is not a full Ubuntu virtual machine including a kernel, and doesn't "boot", it is an Ubuntu userspace (ie the programs that make up Ubuntu) made to run under Windows.  You can't "boot into Ubuntu" from it.  But you can run most common Ubuntu tools from the command line.

Comment: Indeed. It's called "Ubuntu on Windows 10" but the capability would more accurately be called "Elements of Ubuntu Blended into Windows 10." "Ubuntu on Windows" evokes the idea that there's some coherent Ubuntu OS that Windows 10 is running in a built-in VM or container or something. Instead the Ubuntu elements are more like a translation/emulation layer to allow Windows to run programs that work on Ubuntu than a discrete operating system.